# How to add and edit list items in a dual list in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am pretty new to React js and trying different ways to make a to-do list to understand it further. I have a parent component that renders two child components. I figured out how to transfer the items between the two lists. How do I add items to the 2 lists separately from the UI? I am not able to figure that out. I need two input textboxes for each list and also should be able to edit the list items. Can anybody please help me?

```js
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import { Completed } from './Completed'
import { Pending } from './Pending'

export const Items = () => {
    const [items,setItems]=useState([
        {
            id: 1,
            title:'Workout',
            status:'Pending'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title:'Read Books',
            status:'Pending'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title:'Cook Pizza',
            status:'Pending'
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            title:'Pay Bills',
            status:'Completed'
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            title:' Watch Big Short',
            status:'Completed'
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            title:' Make nutrition Plan',
            status:'Pending'
        }
    ])
    const updateStatus=(id,newStatus)=>{
        let allItems=items;
        allItems=allItems.map(item=>{
            if(item.id===id){
                console.log('in here')
                item.status=newStatus;
            }
        return item
        })
        setItems(allItems)
    }
    return (
        <div class="items">
           <Pending items={items} setItems={setItems} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
           <Completed items={items} setItems={setItems} updateStatus={updateStatus}/>
        </div>
    )
}




import React from 'react'

export const Completed = ({items,setItems,updateStatus}) => {
    return (
        <div className="completed">
            <h1>RIGHT</h1>
            {
                    items && items.map(item=>{
                        if(item && item.status==='Completed')
                        return <><p className="item" key={item.id}>{item.title} <button className="mark_pending" key={item.id} onClick={()=>{updateStatus(item.id,'Pending')}}> Move Left</button></p></>
                    })
                }
 
        </div>
    )
}



import React from 'react'

export const Pending = ({items,setItems,updateStatus}) => {

    return (
        <div className="pending">
            <h1>LEFT</h1>

                {
                    items && items.map(item=>{
                        if(item && item.status==='Pending')
                        return <><p className="item" key={item.id}>{item.title} <button  className="mark_complete" key={item.id} onClick={()=>{updateStatus(item.id,'Completed')}}>Move Right</button></p></>
                    })
                }
 
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "separately from the UI" ?

Comment: Please don't use answer to ask question

Comment: Yes I know. I just can't add comments to the question because I have less thatn 50 reputation.

Comment: @widepeepohappy I need a separate input for each list.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const initialStatus = "Pending";

const initialData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Workout",
    status: "Pending",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Read Books",
    status: "Pending",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Cook Pizza",
    status: "Pending",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Pay Bills",
    status: "Completed",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: " Watch Big Short",
    status: "Completed",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    title: " Make nutrition Plan",
    status: "Pending",
  },
];

const Box = ({ id, title, status, setItems, items }) => {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        const newItems = [...items];
        const index = items.findIndex((v) => v.id == id);
        newItems[index].status =
          newItems[index].status == initialStatus ? "Completed" : initialStatus;
        setItems(newItems);
      }}
    >
      {title}
    </button>
  );
};

export const Items = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(initialData);
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
        <h1>LEFT</h1>
        {items
          .filter((v) => v.status === initialStatus)
          .map((props) => (
            <Box {...props} key={props.id} setItems={setItems} items={items} />
          ))}
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
        <h1>Right</h1>
        {items
          .filter((v) => v.status !== initialStatus)
          .map((props) => (
            <Box {...props} key={props.id} setItems={setItems} items={items} />
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Items;
```

Comment: Hi, there no option to add items to the list or edit items?